# Is there an equivalent of JavaScript Generators in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am migrating a [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/) application to ASP.NET MVC and I was wondering if there's an equivalent to [brailjs](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=97) and njs. There's similar [concept](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html) in Ruby on Rails. Currently I use ASPX view engine but maybe switching to Brail Views could bring a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/how-to-renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/) interesting starting of a Rails-like RJS framework for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no equivalent of the Brail / nVelocity JS in ASP.Net's standard view engine. Two options:
Use one of the above view engines / take the source and convert it into the standard view engine.

Interested in how you get on, as I just use jQuery for everything but handcraft